# Не хватает прав на выполнение скрипта

Tags: apache, php, ubuntu

Такая ситуация. Когда пользователь заходит на «сайт» запускается скрипт РНР, из этого скрипта вызывается уже `shell` скрипт. В котором прописаны команды добавления правил в `ibtables`, НО он не выполняется , т.к. для этого требуются рутовские права.

Как их дать (права)? 
И как проверить из под кого запускается скрипт? (я догадываюсь что это `www-data`, но лучше проверить)

Comment: А вы что именно пытаетесь сделать? Может, вам просто поставить fail2ban?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Чтобы увидеть что делается из под www-data, используйте команду вход из под www-data: "su www-data"
2. Уже из под www-data пробуем запускать скрипт в точности так же, как и запущен он в php
3. Очень важно запускать команды полным путем!!! не "sh ~/script.sh" а "/bin/sh /home/user/srcript.sh". Тоже самое касается iptables запускается полным путем "/sbin/iptables"
4. Узнать можно где лежит программа через whereis (whereis iptables)
5. Добавляем в sudoers скрипт: user ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/sh /home/user/srcript.sh
6. Не забываем делать вывод лога в файл для того чтобы понять что происходит со скриптом: /bin/sh /home/user/srcript.sh > /home/user/scriptrun.log

Comment: это кошмар

Answer (score 3):

"Бесправная" работа веб-сервера очень желательна для безопасности сервера. Чтобы сделать необходимую в данной задаче дыру, я бы предложил поступать таким образом:

1. веб скрипт дописывает нужные данные в некий текстовый файл;
2. раз в N минут по крону из-под рута запускается shell-скрипт, который забирает данные из текстового файла и прописывает их в iptables.

Минус — немгновенность внесения изменений.

Comment: Также можно использовать очередь сообщений (zeromq, rabbitmq, memcacheq, gearman). 

С кода веб сайта будет добавляться задача с очередь, а отдельный постоянно запущенный скрипт с правами рута будет читать эту очередь и выполнять необходимые действия.

Comment: так-же можно использовать inotify